# How to count in laravel from different table

Tags: mysql, laravel, count, model, controller

Hei I'm making data table to show how many comment that on my post from user that login and making that post but I got some bug it retrieve only 1 but actually I got like 26 comment, I dont know why.

In my controller:

```
public function getCountComment()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return $all_count = $user->post()
        ->withCount('comment_to_post')
        ->take(5)->get();
}
```

Model **comment.php**:

```
public function comment_to_post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post','id_user');
}
```

I've got like 26 comment but it retrieve only 1 comment count. Hope you can help me guys

> "comment_to_post_count": 1

Comment: Can you try removing the take(5) in your query.

Comment: take 5 will limit number of posts and not number of comments

Comment: already still only 1 retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done like this in my code - hope it helps

```
public function getCountComment()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $posts = $user->posts();

    foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
        $posts[$key]->post_comments_count = PostComment::where('post_id', $value->id)->count(); 
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
public function getCountComment()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $all_count = $user->post()
        ->withCount('comment_to_post')
        ->count();
    return $all_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing **take(5)** method (limit) may fix it..